# How is this returning 0 , when it should be 1

Tags: c

I'm trying to return 1 when the string has only alphabetical characters, but it is always returning 0, i think the problem is on the if, but i don't know why.
Can someone explain, thanks.

```
int ft_str_is_alpha(char *str)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (str[i] != '\0')
    {
        if ((str[i] < 'a' && str[i] > 'z') || (str[i] < 'A' && str[i] > 'Z'))
        {
            return 0;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *str;

    str = "Hello World";
    printf("%s - %d\n", str, ft_str_is_alpha(str));
    str = "H1LLO W0RLD";
    printf("%s - %d\n", str, ft_str_is_alpha(str));
}
```

Comment: `str[i] < 'a' && str[i] > 'z'` this will never be true

Comment: As posted the function always returns `1` . If you are seeing `0` then you are not running this code !

Comment: Make it a habit to read out expressions loud/in your head: "if the character is less than 'a' and greater than 'z'"  ...no, that doesn't make sense. "_or_ greater than" makes sense though.

Answer (score 7):

It's because this composite condition will never be `true`:

```
if ((str[i] < 'a' && str[i] > 'z') || (str[i] < 'A' && str[i] > 'Z')) {
```

A `char` will not be able to be `< 'a'` **and** `> 'z'` at the same time (and the same goes for the capital letters).

What you want is likely:

```
if (!( (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z') || (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z') )) {
```

That is, you want to check if `str[i]` is not in the range `['a','z']` **or** `['A',Z']`.

Alternative version:

```
if ((str[i] < 'a' || str[i] > 'z') && (str[i] < 'A' || str[i] > 'Z')) {
```

Which tests if `str[i]` is outside the range `['a','z']` **and** outside the range `['A','Z']`.

Or just use the [`isalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha) function:

```
if (!isalpha((unsigned char)str[i])) return 0; // if not alphabetic, return 0
```

Note that the `(unsigned char)` cast is necessary to avoid getting [*undefined behavior*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) in case the `char` in `str[i]` is negative.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following that includes the [isalpha()](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/library-function/ctype.h/isalpha) function from ctype.h library:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int ft_str_is_alpha(char *str)
{
    int length = strlen(str);

    for(int i=0; i<length; i++) {
        if (!isalpha( (unsigned char) str[i])) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *str;

    str = "Hello World";
    printf("%s - %d\n", str, ft_str_is_alpha(str));
    str = "H1LLO W0RLD";
    printf("%s - %d\n", str, ft_str_is_alpha(str));
}
```

Also, your strings currently contain spaces, so this code will always return 0 when there are spaces.

If you want to ignore spaces add to your code:

> (!isalpha(str[i]) && !isspace(str[i])